# How to solve $\lim \left(\frac{n^3+n+4}{n^3+2n^2}\right)^{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I can't seem to find a way to solve:

$$\lim \left(\dfrac{n^3+n+4}{n^3+2n^2}\right)^{n^2}$$

I've tried applying an exponential and logaritmic to take the $n^2$ out of the exponent, I've tried dividing the expression, but I don't get anywhere that brings light to the solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: put $n=1/t$ where $t>0$ is small.

Comment: No `\dfrac` in titles please.

Comment: limits at which point? you didn't mention the point.... :(

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha, when using $n$ we usually assume $n \to \infty$ so I omitted that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align*}
L &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^3+n+4}{n^3+2n^2}\right)^{n^2} \\ 
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^3 +2n^2 - 2n^2+n+4}{n^3+2n^2}\right)^{n^2}\tag1 \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1 + \frac{- 2n^2+n+4}{n^3+2n^2}\right)^{n^2} \tag2 \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1 + \frac{- 2n^2+n+4}{n^3+2n^2}\right)^{\frac{n^2(n^3+2n^2)(n-2n^2+4)}{(n^3+2n^2)(n-2n^2+4)}} \tag3 \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}e^{n^2(n-2n^2+4)\over(n^3+2n^2)} \tag4
\end{align*}
$$
Now consider:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}{n^2(n-2n^2+4)\over(n^3+2n^2)} = -\infty
$$

Hence your limit is:
$$
e^{-\infty} = 0
$$

Description of steps:

- $(1)$ add and subtract $2n^2$
- $(2)$ perform division
- $(3)$ multiply the power by the reciprocal of the fraction inside parentheses
- $(4)$ use the limit for $(1 + {1\over x^n})^{x_n}$ when $x_n \to\ \infty$

Comment: Some extra work need to be taken care of in step 4, the limit is $(1+\frac{1}{x^n})^{x_n y_n}\to e^{y_n}$ when $x_n\to \infty$, this is not trivial and I'm not sure it is always true.

Comment: @P.Quinton you may justify this by continuity of $a^x$. Hence $\lim a^{x_n} = a^{\lim x_n}$

Comment: I was actually talking about the step just before that, the fourth

Comment: @P.Quinton well that would be a good candidate for the OP to consider proving it

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \log f(n)  = n^2 \log\dfrac{n^3+n+4}{n^3+2n^2}= n^2 \log (1 - O(\frac{1}{n})) \rightarrow -\infty $$
Hence $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(n) = e^{-\infty} = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that $n\to \infty$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\dfrac{n^3+n+4}{n^3+2n^2}\right)^{n^2}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \Biggl(\left(1+\dfrac{-2n^2+n+4}{n^3+2n^2}\right)^{\dfrac{n^3+2n^2}{-2n^2+n+4}}\Biggr)^{\frac{-2n^4+n^3+4n^2}{n^3+2n^2}}=\ e^{-\infty}=0$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^3+n+4}{n^3+2n^2}\right)^{n^2} =
 \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1+\frac{n+4}{n^3} }{1+\frac{2n^2}{n^3}}\right)^{n^2}=
\frac{e}{\lim_{n\to\infty}e^n}$$

Hence your limit is: 0